# React.js: How to make password validation dynamic?

Tags: reactjs

I use a library called 'password-validator' to somehow make password validation intuitive

Its use case is something like this:

```
schema
       .is().min(8)                                    
       .is().max(20)                                                               
       .has().symbols()                                
       .has().digits() 

schema.validate(newPassword, { list: true }) //will return a array list of failed criteria
```

I would like to make this library dynamic and can get values from a JSON response

Sample of my JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "paramID": "Allowable special characters",
        "value": "~@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?/"
    },
    {
        "paramID": "Force at least one numeric? ",
        "value": "Y"
    },
    {
        "paramID": "Force at least one special character? ",
        "value": "N"
    },
    {
        "paramID": "Maximum password age (days",
        "value": "90"
    },
    {
        "paramID": "Maximum password length",
        "value": "10"
    },
    {
        "paramID": "Minimum password length",
        "value": "1"
    }
]
```

Now, I want to assign these values onto `schema` variable

Tried using `map` function and I was able to iterate the value in the JSON response.

However, how do I match this?

e.g.

```
{
    "paramID": "Minimum password length",
    "value": "1"
}
```

should be put on

```
schema
       .is().min(8)
```

but the value should be from the JSON.

Help please on what ES6 function should I use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to write a logic to match the param id and then do the appropriate action. Like say paramId is "Minimum password length", then you execute schema.is().min(your valuee).

Comment: I would imagine that is like an `if` or `switch` statement, however, how do I tell the system to get that certain value if its for `"Minimum password length"` given that JSON structure. I tried to do this but the values get mixed up

Comment: You just need to iterate over the array, and every time call the apropiate logic based on the param id. The mapping to the paramID and the logic is what you need to take care of. After the loop ends, the schema would dynamically built based on your loop

Comment: Wow it worked. Just needed a `map` and a series of `if-else` statements. Guess I was overcomplicating things lol, thanks.

Comment: @iamjpcbau Sounds like you should probably use `.forEach`, not `.map()`. `.map()` is for transforming the elements of an array into another array.